# Spring Config-Client doesn't refresh if Config-Server is down during initial startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am running a test with a barebones Spring cloud config-server and a client-application. I executed a refresh scenario (by calling /refresh endpoint on the client-application) 
after config-server was down initially. Here is what I found

- Client starts up with locally packaged properties when config-server is not reachable on startup. (I have the properties in application.yml that is bundled with client-application)
- Git backend has different values for the properties compared to locally packaged version. Config-server is aware of the changes in git (Confirmed by connecting directly to config-server)
- I bring up config-server and do a POST to /refresh endpoint on the client-application.
- Client-application is not aware of the new properties from config-server.

In the second usecase

- Client-application starts up and connects to config-server successfully. I see that the values from config-server have been fetched by the client-application successfully
- I make a change in Git and call the /refresh endpoint on the client-application. Properties are refreshed successfully.

At this point it looks like /refresh doesn't work if the client-application comes up initially without being able to successfully connect to config-server. I am doing this to test
a fallback strategy for the client-application if config-server is not reachable when the client-application is starting up. (The fallback strategy is to have locally packaged properties
that will be used if config-server is not available on startup. If the config-server is available then the local properties are overriden). Any pointers to why this is not working and 
what I could do differently? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

**Server-Code**

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Client-Code**

```
@RestController
@RefreshScope
@Component
public class Greeter {
    @Value("${message.greeting}")
    String greeting;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/",produces = "application/json")
    public List<String> index(){
        List<String> env = Arrays.asList("message.greeting: " + greeting);
        return env;
    }

}
```

bootstrap.yml  (On config-client application)

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configclient
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
logging:
  config: classpath:logback.xml
server:
  port: 8000
```

**application.yml**

```
message:
  greeting: Hello from Local!
```

**Config in Git** (Served through config-server)

```
message:
  greeting: Hello from Git-Edited!
```

Comment: can you explain with code and separate questions ?

Comment: Added code sample

Comment: @ThamiraLakmal I don't see the solution you posted yesterday. Did you remove it?

Comment: yes! because it not based on your specific issue. I add actuator and try to solve the problem. but not refresh it.

Comment: if you need some code for other scenarios folllow https://github.com/WThamira/spring-boot-sample-configs.git  and https://github.com/WThamira/spring-boot--configuration-example.git

Comment: While running with fail-fast=false, the config client assumes you don't want to run with config server up.

Comment: @spencergibb, not sure I understand since even with fail-fast=false I can see the client-application connecting to config-server when it starts up.

Answer (score 2):

According to spring-cloud-config documentation -

> If you expect that the config server may occasionally be unavailable
>   when your app starts, you can ask it to keep trying after a failure.
>   First you need to set spring.cloud.config.failFast=true, and then you
>   need to add spring-retry and spring-boot-starter-aop to your
>   classpath. The default behaviour is to retry 6 times with an initial
>   backoff interval of 1000ms and an exponential multiplier of 1.1 for
>   subsequent backoffs. You can configure these properties (and others)
>   using spring.cloud.config.retry.* configuration properties.

Reference -> http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.3.1.RELEASE/