# Spring boot custom resolver for class variable

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
@Controller
public SomeController {
    @CustomConfig("var.a")
    private String varA;

    @CustomConfig("var.b")
    private String varB;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get() {
        return varA;
    }
}
```

CustomConfig would be an @Interface class that accepts one value parameter. The reason why we are not using @Value is because this will not come from config file but from API (such as https://getconfig.com/get?key=var.a). So we are going to make HTTP request to inject it.

So far I've only manage to make something work if the varA and varB is inside get() method as parameter, by using below in a class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    CustomConfigResolver resolver = new CustomConfigResolver();
    argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
}
```

And inside CustomComfigResolver.resolveArgument() we would do the HTTP query, but that's not really what we wanted, we need it to be injected as class variable.

Does anyone have experience in resolving it at class variable level?

Thank you

Comment: How do handle the fact that your remote http service is temporarily down ? Instance variables of spring bean are resolved during application-context startup (actually when your service starts...)... High critical coupling here.

Comment: @CodeScale we actually have this design where this spring boot project does not connect to database, the repo layer will be replaced by something that is connecting to same server we use to get config details, in the event its down, even if we have configs, this project will not work properly. High critical coupling existed without this change.

Answer (score 0):

This could work if you use @Value instead of your own custom annotation. This uses the built in environment:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Configuration
public class TcpIpPropertySourceConfig implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate rest;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
       // Call your api using Resttemplate
        RemoteProperties props = //Rest Call here;

        // Add your source to the environment.
        MutablePropertySources sources = env.getPropertySources();
        sources.addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("customSourceName", props)
    }
}
```

**What you are trying to achieve is difficult when you start to consider "unhappy" scenarios. Server down / not reachable. You need to account for all of that in the method above.**

I would highly recommend to instead use Spring Cloud Config. Great guide on that is here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration

This provides:
- Reloading of your @Value() properties, so no custom annotation needed.
- A more stable server and great Spring integration out of the box.

Best of all, it is easy to apply Retries and Backoffs if the configuration server goes down (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44203216/2082699). This will make sure your app doesn't just crash when the server is not available.

Comment: Well we are actually quite aware of the unhappy scenarios, we are in this micro services architecture where, if the API server is down we do have backups, so in this questions we are actually looking for the actual way to implement @CustomConfig("var.a") on class variable level, and how it can be done. The cloud config doesn't seems close to this requirement though